# c# Tridion 2011 How to get metadata selected keyword from a component

Tags: 2011, c#

In Tridion 2011 I have a componen in which in the metadata fields has a keyword with different values. How should I get the selected value in c#. I tried the next but I get the name of the key not the selected value.

```
ItemFields fields = new ItemFields(component.Metadata, component.MetadataSchema);
KeywordField key = (KeywordField)fields[fieldName];
return key.Name;
```

but I get the name of the keyword not the selected value.
Keyword:
  Business Area
Values:
  Corporate.
  Decorative paints.
  Performance coatings(selected one)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The KeywordField is the field itself, not the chosen Keyword. You need to get it's value... something like this:

```
ItemFields fields = new ItemFields(component.Metadata, component.MetadataSchema);
KeywordField keywordField = (KeywordField)fields[fieldName];
Keyword keyword = (Keyword)keywordField.Value;
return keyword.Title;
```

Comment: You are right. I did the changes and the code works perfect. Thanks a lot